# Data type mismatch: cannot cast struct for Pyspark struct field cast

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, schema

I am facing an exception, I have a dataframe with a column `"hid_tagged"` as struct datatype, My requirement is to change column `"hid_tagged"` struct schema by appending `"hid_tagged"` to the struct field names which was shown below. I am following below steps and getting  "data type mismatch: cannot cast structure" exception.

Can you let me know what I am missing here.

```
df2=df.select(col("hid_tagged").cast(transform_schema(df.schema)))
```

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve &#39;`hid_tagged`&#39; due to data type mismatch: cannot cast struct&

I am able to generate expected struct schema changes using below udf:

**UDF FOR SCHEMA CONVERSION:**

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType

def transform_schema(schema):

  if schema == None:
    return StructType()

  updated = []
  for f in schema.fields:
    if isinstance(f.dataType, StructType):
      
      updated.append(StructField(f.name, transform_schema(f.dataType)))
      
    else:
      
      updated.append(StructField(str("hid_tagged"+f.name),f.dataType, f.nullable))

  return StructType(updated)
```

**Source struct schema:**

```
hid_tagged:struct
    field_1:long
    field_2:long
    field_3:string
    field_4:array
        element:string
    field_5:string
    field_6:string
    field_7:long
    field_8:long
    field_9:long
    field_10:boolean
    field_11:string
    field_12:long
    field_13:long
    field_14:long
    field_15:long
    field_16:long
    field_17:long
    field_18:long
    field_19:long
    field_20:long
```

**Expected Struct schema:**

```
hid_tagged:struct
    hid_tagged_field_1:long
    hid_tagged_field_2:long
    hid_tagged_field_3:string
    hid_tagged_field_4:array
        element:string
    hid_tagged_field_5:string
    hid_tagged_field_6:string
    hid_tagged_field_7:long
    hid_tagged_field_8:long
    hid_tagged_field_9:long
    hid_tagged_field_10:boolean
    hid_tagged_field_11:string
    hid_tagged_field_12:long
    hid_tagged_field_13:long
    hid_tagged_field_14:long
    hid_tagged_field_15:long
    hid_tagged_field_16:long
    hid_tagged_field_17:long
    hid_tagged_field_18:long
    hid_tagged_field_19:long
    hid_tagged_field_20:long
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df2 = df.select(col("hid_tagged").cast(transform_schema(df.schema)['hid_tagged'].dataType))
```

`transform_schema(df.schema)` returns the transformed schema for the whole dataframe. You need to pick out the data type of the `hid_tagged` column before casting.